# Access Azure RoleEnvironment from console application

Tags: c#, .net, azure, assemblies

If I create an console application and just want to get the instance name I try to get it via

```
RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id
```

but this already fails with the outer exception:

> role discovery data is unavailable

and the inner exception:

> The type initializer for
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment' threw an
>   exception. - Could not load file or assembly 'msshrtmi,
>   Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Is there any other way to get the Azure instance name programmatically or does my console application need some special rights to access RoleEnvironment?

Comment: Clearly there's a dependency on `msshrtmi`. Is it in GAC?

Comment: I included it now with "copy to local". The inner exception went away, but the outer exception is still present.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to access RoleEnvironment features that are available as you are not running in the Azure environment / AppFabrix.  I would suggest you check whether you're running is the Azure Environment by using the [RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.isavailable.aspx) member.

A slightly more robust method would be to wrap your instance ID into a method, something like...

```
// Handcoded
private string ApplicationInstanceId(){
    return RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable ?
        RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id :
        "RunningLocally!";
}
```

Comment: I tried it in different Azure VMs and RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable is always returning false.